# How to periodically extract data from a webpage and add it to a Google sheets file?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I want to create a solution for periodically checking a webpage for new data and extracting it a spreadsheet in Google Sheets. It could also be event driven i.e. rather than checking every x period of time it just extracts new data as soon as it gets appears. Why do I want to do this? I do sports betting and want to log my bets so I can track my results, but doing it manually takes time and is tedious.

I have no experience with web scraping, but know basic python if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check if the website has an API. If yes, you can get the data in python with request library (more simple).
If no, you need to scrape this data by using libraries in python like Selenium, beautifoul soup or Playwright. You will find a lot of tutorial of webscraping.
In order to launch the script every X you will need crontab if you're on Linux or Task Planner if you are on Windows.